# Discriminate between MSDU, MMPDU while using Native WiFi for retrieving incoming number of frames?

Tags: wifi

I have some problems whiling using Mircosoft Native Wifi API.

I can use  queryinterface function to get the current value of counter to know the frames received.

But the statistic involves not only MSDU but also MMPDU and MPDU, which cause the result inaccurate.
as the link: [See the site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The members of this structure are used to record MAC-level statistics for:

MAC service data unit (MSDU) packets.

MAC protocol data unit (MPDU) frames.

MPDU frame counters must include all MPDU fragments sent for an MSDU packet.

Management MPDU (MMPDU) frames.

So, is there any way to obtain only the received number of MSDU ??? THX!!